Estoy haciendo un UPDATE a un campo que no permite NULL , en el UPDATE le pongo valor a ese campo , sin embargo me da ERROR de que no permite NULL?
Ejecuto este UPDATE :
Update ORDEN_PROPERTY 
set t_valor='S',  
t_usuario_ult_mod='SISTEMAS' 
where c_id=5                                                  


ERROR at line 1: ORA-01407: cannot update
("ORDEN_PROPERTY"."T_USUARIO_ULT_MOD") to NULL

alguna idea porque sucede ?

bueno.. no se como esta escrito ese query, pero estas seguro que viene de ese query???

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Quizás hay un trigger que convierte el valor a null.
